# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' in Django/djangorestframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

first of all I know there are some answers about this TypeError but none of them resolved my case. I did the research and that is why I am posting this question.

I got sutck at error saying TypeError: unhashable type:'list' in Django/djangorestframework.
I am not even sure where the error is located at because traceback is not that clear to me.

Here is my code:
**serializers.py:**

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """User model serializer"""

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {
                'write_only': True,
                'style': {'input': 'password'}
            }
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create and return a new user"""
        user = User.objects.create_user(email=validated_data['email'], username=validated_data['username'], password=validated_data['password'])

        return user
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\checks.py", line 50, in check_user_model            if not cls._meta.get_field(cls.USERNAME_FIELD).unique:
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 551, in get_field
    return self._forward_fields_map[field_name]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

**models.py:**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils import timezone


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Manager for User model"""
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        """Function for creating a user"""
        if not email:
            return ValueError("Email must be provided")

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, username=username)

        user.set_password(password)

        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        """Function for creating superusers"""
        user = self.create_user(email, username, password)

        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """User database model"""
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = ['email']
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

I think the problem is in my serializer but if you need me to provide any other file please comment and I will update the question.

Comment: can you show the error traceback?

Comment: @JPG Sure, I updated the question

Comment: error tracebacks seem the error is not raised due to the serializer. Are you sure the error remains even after you removed the serializer?

Comment: Anyway, can you add your models.py?

Comment: @JPG yeah you are right, its not due to serializer, I'll update the question?

Comment: Can you show your User model?

Comment: I guess that somehow "field_name" is not a string but a list. You might be able to temporarily manually edit `C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py` and add a line just before line 551 logging/printing what field_name actually is, and then you might be able to work out why/what the problem is from there.

Comment: @JPG Griffioen I added the models.py code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you get is because the underlying code tries to get the username field for the User model, but you have set it to a list instead of a string, which means that it cannot find the specified field.

Change `USERNAME_FIELD = ['email']` to `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`

Comment: Wow, I am so blind, thanks, I'll accept the answer in a minute when I'll be able to